# Convert indented-with-spaces text to PowerPoint ordered/unordered list?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Ok, seems like this should be a no-brainer, but is there an EZ way to go from an indented-with-spaces text like that below to a PowerPoint ordered/unordered list? The end goal is to convert the list to one of those nifty tree-like SmartArt MS-Office hierarchical org charts with landscape orientation. With the help of some code examples on the forums, I was able to knock out a short recursive VBA routine to do so (after locking up my laptop a few times with infinite loops before getting things right!), but was hoping for a less obtuse, preferably look-Ma-no-coding solution. Thanks!

```
A
   B
   C
      D
      E
   F
      G
   H
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a little-known feature of PPT that might help. You can put a fairly large amount of text in a plain text file and open it in PPT or insert it as though inserting slides from a regular PPT file (by forcing the file dialog to allow files of type *.*)

Unindented lines of text become the titles of new slides
@Single-indented lines become level 1 bullets
@@Double-indented lines become level 2 bullets

and so on.  Use an actual tab character where you see @ above.

Comment: Steve, that is an amazing tip! Highlight the resulting  list, convert to SmartArt and done - no recursion muss, no recursion fuss. Thanks!